# Treehouse plans call for a 4x10 beam. Can I sandwich a pair of 2x10 and secure them with glue and screws?

Tags: outdoor, construction

I am trying to build a tree house and I bough plans for it. The plans call for 4x10 beams, which my local big box store doesn't carry. Can I get away with sandwiching 2 2x10 boards using glue and screws? I figure since all the load will be top to bottom, it should be OK. The beams will be attaching to a Tree Attachment Bolt (TAB). Here's the image of the support structure, with the 4x10 beams visible. [image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. Short answer is yes, If someone else doesn't add a formal Answer in a reasonably amount of time I'll add one with additional details. In the meantime, Google "sistered joists" or "sistering joists".

Comment: Agree w @graphus. Just be aware that you’ll need a different joist hanger when you change to a doubled 2x.

Comment: Speaking of big box versus real lumberyard… lumberyard quality is usually higher, they’ll have 4x10s, they’ll deliver, they’ll have the hardware you need, and they’re probably price competitive with the big box. Plus you’ll save time/materials that you’d spend assembling your 2-2x10 beams. I get that this doesn’t help if you live more than 50 miles from a real lumberyard…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preamble: I'm not an engineer. Opinions here represent received wisdom from years as a carpenter. If you *need* the absolute truth, consult a professional engineer and get a stamp on your plans.

There are a lot of variables that go into wood beam sizing. Wood species and grade are the biggies. Predicted live load and acceptable deflection also matter.

As a very general statement, 2-2x10s will span around 10'. So if your treehouse footprint is just a little over 20' per side, you should be fine. (I'm assuming that the middle of the long beams are lagged into the tree... otherwise, that changes that span dramatically.)

Just to repeat the comments, if you switch from a 4x10 to 2-2x10, you'll need different joist hangers, eg Simpson LUS210-2Z, as opposed to LUS410Z. (There are also nicer looking hangers, like the HUC line, if you want.) Making a double 2x10 technically requires 10d nails at 16" oc around the edge. I'd use bigger nails (almost 16d), 3 or 4 at 16" oc, but not too close to the ends. Glue between doesn't really help much.

(Edit, to address glue comments: I agree completely that glue, properly deployed — flat mating surfaces, appropriate moisture content, good clamping, etc — is the strongest solution. In a framing setting, where wood can be wet, uneven, etc, one doesn’t want to rely on glue instead of mechanical fasteners. I think it’s the unpredictability of glue quality that makes professionals just ignore it completely.)

Laziness abounds, so I'll cut and paste my lumberyard vs big box rant: Speaking of big box versus real lumberyard... lumberyard quality is usually higher, they’ll have 4x10s, they’ll deliver, they’ll have the hardware you need, and they’re probably price competitive with the big box. Plus you’ll save time/materials that you’d spend assembling your 2-2x10 beams. I get that this doesn’t help if you live more than 50 miles from a real lumberyard...

Last but not least, handrail post attachment methods have improved in recent years. If your plans don't involve tiebacks (eg Simpson DTT-2Z), do a bit of research. For a little more work, a tieback will produce a much more solid and durable railing.

Comment: Excellent. The only thing I'd take issue with is *"Glue between doesn't really help much"* cos you know how I feel about glue joints. If these were glued together with care and attention boards because in effect a single piece, same as when you glue boards on edge into a panel they act as though those glue joints aren't there. Obviously with all those nails they'd be the fixing and nothing else is needed, but e.g. if glued and screwed the screws could technically be withdrawn after the glue dried. (Although for something like this, why bother taking them out?)

Comment: @Graphus - if the pieces are glued correctly then youre most likely 100% correct - but if someone is gluing long beams, possibly twisted, bowed and probably not very smooth (big box store quality) -  the glue joint may end up quite bad - it would be glued in some places, in some places there may be no glue at all. I would trust glue job for furniture, but for treehouse, I think it's better to be safe (whole 4x10 if possible nails and screws if not) than sorry..

Comment: @JanSpurny, that's why I specified "with care and attention" ;-) [If this were part of an Answer the details on how to accomplish this with some assurance would be provided, rather than it being a throwaway line without explanation.] Also note I did suggest there's no point in taking the screws out, and obviously it doesn't need to be said they could match or exceed what the nails in the spec would provide?

Comment: @Graphus - ok, I get it :) I sometimes focus on some irrelevant detail and I don't see the rest, sorry

Comment: @JanSpurny, de nada. We've all missed the forest for the trees on occasion!

Answer (score 2):

A standard dimensional 4x is 3.5" wide. Two 2x side by side will only be 3" wide (1.5" each). The traditional solution for this when framing door/window headers is to sandwich a layer of plywood/OSB between the two 2x to make the whole sandwich a full 3.5".

This will allow you to use a 4x joist hanger and *should* be sufficiently strong (consult an engineer - I'm not one). Since this is outdoors, you'd probably want to use PT plywood and put some sort of sealer tape on top to help slow (not prevent) water ingress & rot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought experiment. Take a 4 x 10 and span a gap with it. Put a uniform load on it until it deflects some small amount. Now take supersharp, super thin blade and slice the beam down the middle. The deflection of the beam won't change, since there were no lateral or twist forces applied to the beam.

In the real world, there are other considerations such as buckling, but that better not be a consideration - if it is, you've got bigger problems. The point is that if you do it right, and pay attention to issues like FreeMan's dimensional point, it's perfectly safe to build up beams. You don't want to do this in the vertical dimension, of course.

Comment: You might want to elaborate on the final sentence.